# Geometric interpretation of vector norm with more than two elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have a very basic question. Sorry.

The code snippet below defines a simple vector (0.5,2.5), calculates the vector norm (2.55) and plots the vector. It's easy to see that the vector lengths/eculidean distance is about 2.55

However, if I change my vector and include one more element (1.5) in the middle, the norm changes to 2.96.

I understand this when I look at how the norm is calculated, but how should interpret vector2 geometrically? Why is the vector longer when the tail and head are the same?

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vector = np.array([0.5, 2.5])

def normVector(v):
    return np.round(np.sqrt(np.sum(v**2)),2)

print(normVector(vector))

plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,4.5))

a1 = plt.arrow(0,0,v[0],v[1],head_width=.3,width=.1,color='k',length_includes_head=True)

plt.grid(linestyle='--',linewidth=.5)
plt.axis('square')
plt.axis([-4,4,-3,4])
plt.legend([a1],['v1', 'v2'])

plt.show()

vector2 = np.array([0.5,1.5 2.5])

print(vector2)
```
````

Comment: Are you asking what is the difference between the norm of a point $(x,y)$ in the plane and the norm of a point $(x,y,z)$ in $3$-space?

Comment: if you have a stick and light source directly above it, what happens when you lift one end of the stick while the other remains on the ground? does the shadow remain the same or does it get smaller? in your example the shadow(on the xz plane) has remained the same even though you've lifted one end of the stick, which means the stick iteself must have gotten longer. it's like me saying the vector (2,10) has the same length as (2,0) just because they have the same x component. just draw the vectors and it becomes obvious which is longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\vec v=(a,b)$ is some vector in $xy$-plane, then it's norm is defined as $\|v\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. You can view it as a length of a diagonal of a rectangle with sides of lengths $a$ and $b$. Similarly if we define $\vec{w}=(a,b,c)$ as some vector in 3d space, then it's norm will be the same as that of a diagonal of cubiod with sides $a,b$ and $c$, or $\|w\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$.

It is similiar for all n-dimensional Euclidian spaces.